# Change depth first algorithm from recursion to iteration

Tags: python, iteration

I'm trying to figure out a way to convert the function `helper` from recursion to iteration, using some form of loop.

I'm actually stumped right now and I'm wondering if any of you guys can help. It's a function created to search if the given start and ending point path exists within a directed graph using a depth first traversal.

```
def helper(graph, current, visited):
    if current in graph:
        for neighbor in graph[current]:
            if neighbor not in visited:
                visited.append( neighbor )
                helper(graph, neighbor, visited)

def DFS(graph, start, goal):
    if start not in graph and goal not in graph:
        return False
    visited = [start]
    helper(graph, start, visited)
    return goal in visited
```

Answer (score 4):

The solution is using an explicit stack:

```
stack = [start]
while len(stack) > 0:
    node = stack.pop()
    for x in graph[node]:
        if x not in visited:
            visited.add(x)
            stack.append(x)
```

As a side note your code is using a list for `visited` and this will make things `O(n^2)` slow, you can use a `set` instead. Also you could exit immediately on finding the goal if that presence/absence check is all you need from your search.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a stack for depth first (or a queue for breadth first).

```
def helper(graph, start, visited):
    stack = [ start ]
    while len(stack) > 0:
        current = stack.pop()
        if current in graph:
            for neighbor in graph[current]:
                if neighbor not in visited:
                    visited.append( neighbor )
                    stack.append(neighbor)
```